# VS Express 2013 for Web programmatic id not updating in aspx dot cs tab

Tags: c#, asp.net

Why when i add new buttons in the design tab then change their ID names , they don't get updated at aspx dot cs page?

at first i couldn't click on the server controls and enter into their aspx dot cs page because i used same project folder for VS  express for web and desktop and i am using separate folders for each but get this naming problem

Comment: are you using namespace at all in your .cs files

Comment: yes am using using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

Comment: when i update the name in the events properties it gives me the new name and the old name for the server controls for example:

Comment: protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

Comment: and protected void myNewRad_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

Comment: Do you mean when you change radio button's id in design tab the event handler name in .cs file does not change for e.g. `RadioButton1` is changed to `myNewRad` but handler name remains `RadioButton1_CheckedChanged`?

Comment: not using level namespace from a class level.. do a msdn search on `namespace` to understand what I am talking about... also if you are going to post code.. then post the code in your original question